# What does metatable field __index actually means?

Tags: lua

In Programming in Lua, I known the metatable field `__index` is a function that takes 2 arguments, they are:

1. table itself
2. key value

But something confusing happens when I was reading Object-Oriented Programming, Chapter 21, there is an example(like it):

```lua
local A = {
    greet = function()
        print 'hello world'
    end
}

local B = {}

setmetatable(B, {
    __index = A
})

B.greet()
```

I cant understand why `__index = A` let `B` becomes an object of `A`, it should be a funciton here, right? Just like following:

```lua
__index = function(_, key)
    return A[key]
end
```

Comment: Does the table and the function have something in common?

Comment: please read the manual. you cannot possibly use advanced concepts like metatables successfully without referring to the manual

Comment: In "Programming in Lua" (present from the 1st edition) : "The use of the __index metamethod for inheritance is so common that Lua provides a shortcut. Despite the name, the __index metamethod does not need to be a function: It can be a table, instead. When it is a function, Lua calls it with the table and the absent key as its arguments. When it is a table, Lua redoes the access in that table."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.1):

> __index: The indexing access operation table[key]. This event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. The
> metavalue is looked up in the metatable of table. The metavalue for
> this event can be either a function, a table, or any value with an
> __index metavalue. If it is a function, it is called with table and key as arguments, and the result of the call (adjusted to one value)
> is the result of the operation. Otherwise, the final result is the
> result of indexing this metavalue with key. This indexing is regular,
> not raw, and therefore can trigger another __index metavalue.

In your example `__index` is assigned `A`. So if a key is not present in `B` it is looked up in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The __index metamethod will be triggered when a key not exists.
So take a deeper look at...

```
tab = setmetatable({}, {__index = function(self, key) return('The Index Key ' .. key .. ' do not exists') end})

print(tab.i_am_a_human)
-- Output: The Index Key i_am_a_human do not exists

tab.i_am_a_human = 'yes'
print(tab.i_am_a_human)
-- Output: yes
```

I personally prefer a __index table with functions that will become methods for the table.
Lets say i wanna a table with all table library functions...

```
tab = setmetatable({}, {__index = table})
tab:insert('Hello')
tab:insert('World')
print(tab:concat(' '))
-- Output: Hello World
```